# Any way for the root directory not to have a favicon but a subfolder yes via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

A subfolder, for example named *wow*, contains a favicon file. The script files included in that subfolder don't have the favicon META tags.
I need to set the favicon to appear only to the index file of that subfolder, not to other subfolders or the root one.
If I add this code to the .htaccess file located in the root directory, the favicon still appears in the index of the root directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Prevent directory listings.
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico wow/favicon.ico [L]
```

So is it possible to exclude the subfolder favicon from the root index file via .htaccess?
Notice that in the future the root index file will have its own favicon, and each future subfolder will have their own unique favicons, so in case it is doable, I don't want that function broken.

Comment: If you did not explicitly specify the favicon location in your HTML code, then browsers will request `/favicon.ico` automatically. If you now want to treat that request differently, based on where it was “made from” - then you have no other choice to base that decision on, than the referrer.

Comment: And you will probably have to disable caching for the favicon as well.